# sizeWithFont ios 7.0 deprecated

Tags: ios, sizewithfont

I have following warning to use code in iOS 7.0 it will display that use `sizeWithAttribute:` here is the following code that I have used:

```
messageSize = [theMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0]];
```

if any one have suggestion how to remove the above code with `sizeWithAttribute:` so please tell me.

Comment: Try to do some search before posting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGSize size = [theMessage sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName:
                         [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f]}];
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: thnx man it will work for me

Answer (score 0):

Use sizeWithAttributes: instead, which now takes an NSDictionary. Pass in the pair with key UITextAttributeFont and your font object like this:

```
CGSize size = [string sizeWithAttributes:
                       @{NSFontAttributeName:
                         [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20.0f]}];
```

Thanks